# How to redirect from http to https..?

Tags: java, apache, rest, servlets

Which is the best way to redirect from http to https without hardcoding any values..?

I've tryid to do it in code, but could be a better way to do it in server side?

Comment: You mean from the `HttpServletResponse` `redirect()` method?

Comment: I think I rather would like to do it in Apache side but it still would be intresting to know how to redirect() a HttpServletResponse from http to https without hardcoding any values..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming you mean in Apache, your virtualhost should be like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    # ... SSL configuration goes here
</VirtualHost >
```

If you are thinking about using mod_rewrite:

The use of RewriteRule to perform this task may be appropriate if there are other RewriteRule directives in the same scope. This is because, when there are Redirect and RewriteRule directives in the same scope, the RewriteRule directives will run first, regardless of the order of appearance in the configuration file

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html

Comment: You write that `RewriteRule` may be *appropriate*, but from the title of the linked article it seems you mean to say *not appropriate*. I could be wrong. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I mean't that it doesn't seem the best option, except if you are already using mod_rewrite in that virtualhost for other purposes.

Comment: looks like working example..